# How to add Controls to my ToolBox from another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, toolbox

Im having issues adding UserControls into my Toolbox from another project in my solution.

The main project is "AppDesigner" the new Project is "AppDesigner.UI"

Both reflect the namespace.

Withing the main project (AppDesigner) I added a reference to the other project by right clicking on References->Add Reference Then checked the AppDesigner.UI item from Solution.

I have also cleaned and built the project again but I do not see the item in the toolbox.

The `AppDesigner` project has been set to

- OutputType:Windows Application
- .NET Target Version:4
- Default NS: AppDesigner

The `AppDesigner.UI` project has been set to

- OutputType:Class Library
- .NET Target Version:4
- Default NS: AppDesigner.UI

[image]

Comment: Close and reopen VS 2013 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you.
Open Toolbox->Right Click->Choose Items->Browse-> Select the dll or exe.

Comment: Thanks, this also didnt work. I have done everything like I always do but it just wasnt working. 
It turns out the issue is because the build profile conflicts. 1 proj is set to Any CPU and the other to only x86.